# UICollectionViewDropProposal: Move intents

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm working with drag and drop, using a collection view. Is there possible to return UICollectionViewDropProposal (in the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal` method) with both intents: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath and .insertIntoDestinationIndexPath? I would like to recive a feature like on iOS Reminders. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue, using a `CGPoint` value from the location(in:) method. At first - in the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal` method - app gets a cell based on a destinationIndexPath. Then, I get a `CGPoint` value of a dragging cell in regard to the destination cell. That way, you may return a `UICollectionViewDropProposal` value based on the `CGPoint value`. Here's my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {

  //...

  if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: correctDestinationIndexPath) {
           let locationInCell = session.location(in: cell)
              if locationInCell.y <= 25 {
                        return  UICollectionViewDropProposal.init(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
                    } else {
                        return  UICollectionViewDropProposal.init(operation: .move, intent: .insertIntoDestinationIndexPath)
                    }
   }
}
```